# strategy entry and exit setting

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a few questions I want to ask. I have a Pine script v5 script, my strategy actually works fine, but there are some problems with them in this position entry and exit. For example, when the long is opened, it should first close the short, then open the long, and do the same in the reverse operation, first to open the short, first close the long and then open the short, I could not achieve this. They told me to write strategy.close before strategy.entry, but that doesn't work in order, sometimes the entry code works first, sometimes the close code works first, the most important thing for me is that close should work first and then entry should work. But in the code that I have mentioned below, even though close start is done, mostly the entry code works first, then the close code comes into play and sometimes the opposite happens.

Thank you for your help.

```
longCondition = bull 
if long  and (isFirstTrade() or secondTrade) and okToTrade and okToTradeInSession and open_all_longs 
  
    strategy.close(id= 'Short', comment = "Exit SL Short" , alert_message=i_alert_txt_exit_SL_short)
    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long,  alert_message=i_alert_txt_entry_long, comment = "Long")
    strategy.exit(id='Exit SL Long', comment = "Exit SL Long", from_entry='Long', stop= final_SL_Long , limit = TP2longPrice , alert_message = i_alert_txt_exit_SL_long)

    

shortCondition = bear 
if  short and (isFirstTrade() or secondTrade) and okToTrade and okToTradeInSession and open_all_shorts 

    strategy.close(id = 'Long', comment = "Exit SL Long", alert_message=i_alert_txt_exit_SL_long)
    strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short, oca_type = strategy.oca.cancel , alert_message=i_alert_txt_entry_short, comment = "Short")
    strategy.exit(id='Exit SL Short', comment = "Exit SL Short", from_entry='Short', stop=final_SL_Short , limit =TP2shortPrice,  alert_message = i_alert_txt_exit_SL_short)
```

Comment: Do you mean that the notification from the strategy about closing a position and the notification from the strategy about opening a position are reversed? Is this also visible in the alert log, or is it just the order of the webhooks that is broken?

Comment: What I want is the order of the warning messages, for example, when the long signal comes, the short position should be closed first and then the long position open signal should come in order. Currently, the irregular signal is coming.